# Setting cookie in wordpress widget

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I am new to wordpress developing and i want to create a widget which checks if a user has already visited my site. So if it's the first time he visits I'll just show "Welcome" and else I'll show "Welcome back". I thought the easiest way to do this is by setting a cookie. However I cannot set a cookie in my widget it results in an ERROR: Cannot modify header already sent.
   [My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxQBy.jpg)

Comment: Hi, you're pretty new so I just want to leave a couple tips before you get discouraged by the lack of votes! First, you've got a great question and you've given us a lot of detail which is good. You do lack some points of the Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but you've also shown us what you've tried and why it won't work, so that's better than most. My last recommendation is that you copy your code into a code block for everyone to see with your question (Markdown is a dev standard these days: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting cookies way too late (after some content has been output), thus you're getting that error. To avoid that, set the cookie by hooking to an early action, like `init` or `wp`

Comment: Hey thanks for the response! But if I hook it earlier and the widget checks if the cookie exists It will always exist and always display welcome back!

Comment: Good point. You could use some global variable. Like, check if cookie exists on `init` or `wp`. If it doesn't, set it to needed value and set your global to say `NULL` if it does, set it to the value of cookie or to 1, then in widget do `is_null($your_global_var)`. if it's `NULL`, say 'Welcome', otherwise say 'Welcome back`